# linux + is it possible to understand when filesystem was created on disk

Tags: linux, rhel, filesystems, ext4, mkfs

is it possible to understand , when filesystem was created on disk ( date and time )

we try the following ( on sdb disk )

```
 tune2fs -l /dev/sdb   | grep time
Last mount time:          Mon Aug  1 19:17:48 2022
Last write time:          Mon Aug  1 19:17:48 2022
```

but we get only the last mount and last write

what we need is when filesystem created by `mkfs` command

from `lsblk -f` we get:

```
lsblk -f | grep sdb

sdb                ext4              cc0f5da9-6bbc-42ff-8f5a-847497fd993e   /data/sdb
```

so what actually we need is when `mkfs` was running ( `date & time` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically a device `/dev/sdb` contains a partition table, not a filesystem. It's each individual partition that would contain a filesystem. However, since your example uses `/dev/sdb` itself I'll also use that here.

Using your own `tune2fs` command and looking at the output:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdb
```

it's possible to see *by inspection* that there is a creation date. For example,

```
Filesystem created:       Fri Jul  1 13:11:44 2016
```